# Socket Programming - Does Server Queue Requests?

Tags: java, sockets, spring-boot

I am working on socket programming on Java recently and something is confusing me. I have three questions about it.

**First one is;**

There is a `ServerSocket` method in Java. And this method can take up to 3 parameters such as `port`, `backlog` and `ip address`. Backlog means # of clients that can connect as a form of queue into a server. Now lets think about this situation.

> What happens if 10 clients try to connect this server at the same
>   time?

Does Server drop last 5 clients which tried to connect? Lets increase the number of clients up to 1 million per hour. How can I handle all of them?

---

**Second question is;**

Can a client send messages concurrently without waiting server's response? What happens if a client sends 5 messages into server that has 5 backlog size?

---

**The last one is not a question actually**. I have a plan to manage load balancing in my mind. Lets assume we have 3 servers running on a machine.

Let the servers names are A, B and C and both of them are running smoothly. According to my plan, if I gave them a priority according to incoming messages then smallest priority means the most available server. For example;

Initial priorities -> A(0), B(0), C(0) and respond time is at the end of 5. time unit.

1.Message -> A (1), B(0), C(0)

2.Message -> A (1), B(1), C(0)

3.Message -> A (1), B(1), C(1)

4.Message -> A (2), B(1), C(1)

5.Message -> A (2), B(2), C(1)

6.Message -> A (1), B(2), C(2)

.
.
.

Is this logic good? I bet there is a far better logic. What do I do to handle more or less a few million requests in a day?

PS: All this logic is going to be implemented into Java Spring-Boot project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your first question, the backlog queue is something where the clients will be held in wait if you are busy with handling other stuff (IO with already connected client e.g.). If the list grows beyond backlog, the those news clients will get a connection refused. You should be ok with 10 clients connect at the same time. It's long discussion, but keep a thread pool, as soon you get a connected socket from accept, hand it to your thread pool and go back to wait in accept. You can't support millions of client "practically" on one single server period! You'll need to load balance.

Your second question is not clear, clients can't send messages, as long as they are on the queue, they will be taken off the queue, once you accept them & then it's not relevant how long the queue is.

And lastly your question about load balancing, I'd suggest if you are going to have to serve millions of clients, invest in some good dedicated load-balancer :), that can do round robin as well as you mentioned.

With all that said, don't reinvent the wheel :), there are some open source java servers, my favorite: https://netty.io/

Comment: What do you think about using netty with ribbon load balancer?

I am asking all these questions because there is a scenario that i have to deal with it.

I have 2 servers up and running. I have to write client side and send million request to the Server. While doing requests I have to balance the load between two Servers. It is two right now but in the future, Number of the servers might be increase.

Anyway. Should I use netty to send requests and ribbon to load balance? Is it appropriate? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, netty should be fine for client side as well, though I have mostly used java or native sockets api e.g. winsock for C++, for client side code. Also, with clients sending millions of requests, the clients will run on different machines? or same client on a single machine sending all those requests?

Answer (score 3):

> What happens if 10 clients try to connect this server at the same time?

The javadoc explains it:

> The backlog argument is the requested maximum number of pending connections on the socket. Its exact semantics are implementation specific. In particular, an implementation may impose a maximum length or may choose to ignore the parameter altogther.

.

> Lets increase the number of clients up to 1 million per hour. How can I handle all of them?

By accepting them fast enough to handle them all in one hour. Either the conversations are so quick that you can just handle them one after another. Or, more realistically, you will handle the various messages in several threads, or use non-blocking IO.

> Can a client send messages concurrently without waiting server's response?

Yes.

> What happens if a client sends 5 messages into server that has 5 backlog size?

Sending messages has nothing to do with the backlog size. The backlog is for **pending connections**. Messages can only be sent once you're connected.

> All this logic is going to be implemented into Java Spring-Boot project.

Spring Boot is, most of the time, not used for low-level socket communication, but to expose web services. You should probably do that, and let standard solutions (a  reverse proxy, software or hardware) do the load-balancing for you. Especially given that you don't seem to understand how sockets, non-blocking IO, threads, etc. work yet.